# How to show only the name of one category above each posts in frontpage?

Tags: categories, frontpage

I have set the frontpage in my Wordpress installation to show the latest posts. My theme supports the display of the meta category name above each post. Now the problem is each time I publish a new post, I get:

```
Published in "Forntpage", "such-and-such category"
```

in the mentioned area. I would like to have only the name of the relevant category and not the frontpage name there. If I uncheck the frontpage category name from within Wordpress while I am publishing a post, then that post does not appear in the frontpage. I wonder if there is a solution to this problem?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds interesting - that's not how the front page in WordPress usually works. By default, all your latest posts will display unless you specifically set a certain *page* (not *post*) to act as your home page through Settings -> Reading.

It sounds as if your theme is doing something a little bit custom.

Having said that, there are still ways you can hide it. The easiest that comes to mind is editing your theme directly, but that isn't recommended because your customisations will be overwritten if and when you update your theme.

So the better option would be to [set up a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and then copy the file that is generating that category list into your child theme. It's hard to say exactly which file it would be because it depends on how the theme is set up, but it *could* be in home.php, archive.php, index.php or even a separate file that is called by one of those files (you could look at the HTML source for something near the category list and search your theme files to find that).

Once you've located the code that is outputting the categories, you just need to modify it (in your child theme) so that `if` the category is equal to this one you don't want to display, it skips it. I couldn't give you the appropriate code for this without seeing how it's written at the moment, so feel free to edit this code into your question if you'd like.

I realise this doesn't 100% solve the problem for you yet, but I trust it gives you some direction in finding how to go about it! The problem is that it's hard to know exactly how your theme has chosen to do this - and in the end, it might even be better to ask this of your theme's creators.

Comment: You were wight. It was due to an "exclude_category" function in my functions.php file. Thanks.

Comment: @developer Aha! Glad you solved it. :)